# Which arguments are passed to handler bound to Backbone.Model change event?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I can't seem to find any documentation for this and playing around with the code hasn't helped me understand this completely.

I have Backbone model and in my my I bind a handler to the model change event:

```
var myModel = new ModelA();

var myView = new ViewA({
  model: myModel
})

//in my view I have
this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.handleChange);
```

Can someone please explain to me what arguments are passed to **this.handleChange**? I see 
there are 2 arguments, **model** & **value**, but what are they exactly?

What happens when I bind to a specific attribute, like so:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:attr", this.handleChange);
```

When I unset an attribute from the model using **myModel.unset("attr");**, what are the values passed to handleChange? I see that in some cases value is undefined and sometimes it has 1 attribute **unset = true**

Any help or point to relevant documentation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code:

Event `change:attr`:

```
this.trigger('change:' + changes[i], this, current[changes[i]], options);
```

Event `change`:

```
this.trigger('change', this, options);
```

So in the first case, the arguments are: the model, the value, and the options used (both external and internal options (for example, `unset: true` for your `unset` call)). In the second case, as it doesn't concern a particular attribute, the arguments are: the model and the options.

Comment: So if I understand, in the first case, with an attribute, I get the new value of that attribute (i.e. the value after the change)? And if I had unset that attribute, I will get: the model, undefined, and any options (like unset:true)?

Comment: What are the internal & external options that are passed? How are they decided?

Comment: @elanh to your first comment: should be that yeah; to your second: the external are what you chose, the internal are the ones used by default (see the default behavior of the methods) plus some that are necessary for the internal mechanisms (like the unset flag because unset uses set in fact).